# SegFault on parsing an mp3 file with module pymedia

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, mp3

I'm learning python, i want create a mp3/wav player and i use pymedia and python2 to do this.
I'm trying to execute this code but the terminal say me "segmentation fault(core dumped)". Why?

Part of class "play":

```
import pymedia
import time
demuxer = pymedia.muxer.Demuxer('mp3')
testsong = "/home/user/Musica/Avicii/True/YouMakeMe.mp3"
f = open(testsong, 'rb')
spot = f.read()
frames = demuxer.parse(spot) ## SEGMENTATION FAULT ####
decoder = pymedia.audio.acodec.Decoder(demuxer.streams[0]) 
frame = decoder.decode(spot)
sound = pymedia.audio.sound
print frame.bitrate, frame.sample_rate
song = sound.Output(frame.sample_rate, frame.channels, 16)
while len(spot) > 0:
    try:
        if frame:
            song.play(frame.data)
            spot = f.read(512)
        frame = decoder.decode(spot)
    except:
        pass
```

**edited according to the comments**:

I removed the global variable and removed the unnecessary code. If I cut all, except this:

```
import pymedia
import time

demuxer = pymedia.muxer.Demuxer('mp3')

testsong="/home/user/Musica/Avicii/True/YouMakeMe.mp3"
f=open(testsong, 'rb')
spot=f.read()
frames = demuxer.parse(spot) #Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)
```

yields a segfault also.

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ + it looks like you don't really need to use globals in your code—globals are a very bad idate 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Also, you should only post a simplified version of your code that contains only the stuff that is needed to reproduce the bug; everything irrelevant should be removed; see http://sscce.org

Comment: What happens if you chop out all but the three lines beginning `testsong = …`? If you still get a segmentation fault using the basic  open/read something is probably wrong with your Python installation.

Comment: +1 well presented question and update (and your English is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You have almost certainly hit a bug in the pymedia module, which, according to the [Python Wiki is "Not updated since 2006"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic). It is possible that your testsong is defective, but a well written Python library should not segfault even on bad inputs.

You have not said what you are trying to accomplish, but the link above or the [Audio page of the official Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio) would be a good place to look for an alternative library.